# tuning kernel modules parameter

Tags: linux-kernel

I am quite new to Linux and I was going through some online tutorial
and got over two ways for altering the kernel parameter:

1. create `/lib/modprobe.d/XYZ.conf` file and put for example something like `options cdrom lockdoor=0`
2. navigate to `/etc/sysctl.d`, create some file like `mnq.conf` and put something like `aaa.bbb.ccc=0`

What is the difference between these two ways?

Answer (score 0):

To understand the difference, let's see when these parameters are applied to the boot process:

1. Kernel (`vmlinuz`) is loaded with default `sysctl` parameters (nowhere to read actual parameters yet). No modules (drivers) are present at the moment (these are separate entities!).
2. Kernel reads initial ram disk with modules
3. Kernel loads modules for disk drivers and other modules needed for booting. These drivers might need some tuning (i.e. certain SCSI devices might cause initialization timeouts without proper setting). These settings also need to be applied before starting driver initialization, hence `modprobe` and *module params* in general implementation.
4. ...
5. System services are starting including sysctl service which applies both `kernel` and some module parameters dynamically (at runtime). Those parameters doesn't affect workability of the kernel, rather than simple stability/performance tuning.